# Remote user input

Tags: powershell, user-input, remoting

Would it be possible to generate a popup at a remote computer that requires (remote) user input? Let's say i use Powershell to execute a script on a remote computer and want the active user behind that computer to accept running the script. I'f this isn't possible by default, would there be any simple third party solutions (that require NO installation on the remote users computer) i could use to achieve the same goal?

Thinking out of the box i could use powershell to send mail and then scan for incoming replies, but that just feels inefficient.

Comment: You might try creating a scheduled task to run as the interactive user and starting it immediately. I'm not sure if you can get that to pop something up, never tried. Otherwise getting something to execute in the context of the logged on user is a bit of a pain.

Comment: @Chris Dent Interesting option. Will look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually very close to making something like this using the Toast messages API from the UWP.
I can create toast messages with buttons and textboxes (also on a remote machine by using Invoke-Command), I have however been unsuccesfull in getting the results back from the inputs or buttons (and going through the UWP documentation it looks like this is not possible with Powershell).

Sample code I've been working on (look through the documentation of the Toast messages in UWP for more info - this version allows you to run this local or remote. I've not included the XML content for a button but that's easy to implement if you follow the API documentation that Microsoft wrote) - maybe you'll have more luck (disclaimer : this was just my first working concept, code isn't optimized yet, a lot of duplicate code for the "local" and "remote" version etc.) :

```
Function Invoke-ToastMessage
{
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param
        (
        [string]$Message,
        [string]$Notifier = "Administrators",
        [string]$ComputerName = $null
        )

[scriptblock]$ToastScriptRemote = {
$Message = $args[0]
$Notifier = $args[1]
# XML Template
[xml]$XmlTemplate = @"
<toast scenario="reminder">
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
      <text>Admin Notification</text>
      <text>$Message</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
  </actions>
</toast>
"@
    # fake load the assemblies
    [void][Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification,Windows.UI.Notifications,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
    [void][Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument,Windows.Data.Xml.Dom,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
    $FinalXML = [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument]::new()
    $FinalXML.LoadXml($XmlTemplate.OuterXml)
    ## create the toast
    $Toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($FinalXML)
    ## Show the TOAST message
    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($Notifier).show($Toast)
    }

[scriptblock]$ToastScriptLocal = {
# XML Template
[xml]$XmlTemplate = @"
<toast scenario="reminder">
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
      <text>Admin Notification</text>
      <text>$Message</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
  </actions>
</toast>
"@
    # fake load the assemblies
    [void][Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification,Windows.UI.Notifications,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
    [void][Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument,Windows.Data.Xml.Dom,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
    $FinalXML = [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument]::new()
    $FinalXML.LoadXml($XmlTemplate.OuterXml)
    ## create the toast
    $Toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($FinalXML)
    ## Show the TOAST message
    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($Notifier).show($Toast)
    }

if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ComputerName))
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $ToastScriptRemote -ArgumentList $Message,$Notifier
    }
    else {$ToastScriptLocal.Invoke()}
}
```

Comment: Thats a nice idea using UWP. Too bad it's not possible to remote return user input. in case u haven't come across this post already, i found some examples using your method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts